# How to send message to queue in ActiveMQ Artemis via GUI

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have Apache ActiveMQ Artemis installed and want to populate a queue via the GUI with a message.

I navigate to queues --> Select queue --> operations

There is a function `sendMessage(java.util.Map,int,java.lang.String,boolean,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)`

The screen looks like :

[image]

For the Type, I add in 1 and for the Body I add in "Test"

When I click execute, the queue does not get populated.

Is there something else I need to do to populate the queue via Artemis GUI ?

Comment: Can you list what version of ActiveMQ Artemis you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easier if you navigate to the queue in the left navigation panel, click the queue, and then click the `Send` button:

[image: Send Button]

And then it will give you a screen to send with headers and payload:

[image: Send Page]

The one you're looking at is invoking the `JMX` command directly; which should work fine! But it may be wonky if your payload and headers aren't formatted correctly to post to the `Jolokia` endpoint.

You might not be seeing the `Send` button I mentioned because you need to be logged in with a write-able role (i.e. admin, or configured user with that role).

Answer (score 1):

In the current version v2.11.0 the "Send" button is not easy to find. With an **admin** user you have to **select the queue** from the left navigation panel. Then with **a click on the down-arrow** on the tab right side, you get a list of the actions allowed. The last one is the "Send" action.

[image: ActiveMQ GUI Send Message]

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the clickable "Send" link shown above may not appear in your version of the Artemis ActiveMQ console as shown.  On my version 2.1.0, you have to click this icon in the upper right hand part of the screen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSPum.png)