# Sending String property with Json message in Artemis UI

Tags: jackson, jms, activemq-artemis

I want to be able to send a list of my own objects with the String property "JMSType" using the 'Send' functionality of the Artemis UI as described in [How to send message to queue in ActiveMQ Artemis via GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49633057/how-to-send-message-to-queue-in-activemq-artemis-via-gui).

I see it allows me to add headers but is there any way to send a String property?  My application can't deserialize the JSON in the queue with Jackson unless JMSType is sent through.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using? Why can you set the header/property using the `Send` command mentioned in the answer to the question you linked?

Comment: I see no way to set properties in the ui. Only headers.  Can't give the version right now.

Comment: `JMSType` *is* a header, though, as noted in the [`javax.jms.Message` JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html). It even pops up for auto-completion when you start typing in the text field. Does that not work for you?

Comment: It doesn't, no.  The reason I assumed it wasnt a header is that when I open a message from a source of that object and inspect it in the UI it says it's a string property.  When I tried adding jmstype as a header the message never arrived at the application listening to the destination.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by, "...when I open a message from a source of that object..." *What* "object"? Is the listening application using a selector so that it only receives messages with a certain `JMSType`? If not, how is it discriminating?

Comment: It would be helpful to add details to your question about what you tried, what you expected, and what you actually observed. Screenshots would be helpful as well since were dealing with a GUI application.